# how to create consumer group with multiple consumers in confluent-kafka-go?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, librdkafka

As i'm new to Go and kafka , i need to implement consumer groups using confluent-kafka-go module. can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `confluent-kafka-go`, you just need to set `group.id` in your consumer configuration to have it join/create a group.

For example:

```golang
c, err := kafka.NewConsumer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
        "bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
        "group.id":          "my-group"})
```

One of the samples demonstrates that: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/examples/consumer_example/consumer_example.go

Comment: what to do if i want to add multiple consumers to that group?

Comment: Just start multiple consumers, all with the same value for `group.id`

Comment: Thank you Mickael Maison. one more doubt ... what to do if i want multiple consumers for multiple groups?

Comment: A consumer can only be a member of a single group. So you need to start some consumers with `group.id` set to `group-1` and some with `group-2` for example.

Comment: can I have more than one consumer in specific go thread?

Comment: Also when I close the consumer, the offsets are changed. (without consuming)

Comment: @MickaelMaison it would be nice of you to help me in this issue.

Comment: @MickaelMaison, thats clear from doc, but how to read messages from many consumers?